# How to add the unhandled exceptions accross the applications in response body in WEB API

Tags: asp.net-web-api

How to add the unhandled exceptions accross the applications in response body in WEB API. If there is no exceptions a success message needs to be sent to the response body for all the responses....Need help on achieving this.

Comment: you need to elaborate your question and provide your code to show how you tried

Comment: I'm using exception class in each model and append the class to the return response message from WEB API.

Answer (score 2):

You need two things. For handling the exceptions, you need to set the IncludeDetailErrorPolicy  in the HttpConfiguration object,

You can configure the error policy preferences as part of the configuration object (HttpConfiguration) in the IncludeErrorDetailPolicy property. This is just an enum that instructs Web API about how to deal with exceptions.

The possible values for this enum are,

Default: It’s uses the customErrors configuration settings if you are using ASP.NET as host or LocalOnly for self-host.
LocalOnly: Only includes error details for local requests
Always: Always includes error details
Never: Never includes error details

When an exception happens, Web API will check the value on this setting for including details about the exception in the response message or not. For example, if Always is enabled, Web API will serialize the exception details as part of the message that you get as response.

The success message does not make much sense as you already have the response status code. A status code equals to OK means that everything went ok. If you still want to add an additional message, use a HttpMessageHandler that checks for the response status code. If the status code is OK, add the message. However, the response body has been set already at that point so you will not able to modify it. You might able to add a message as a header.

Comment: One comment - you can still change the response body in an HttpMessageHandler. The response hasn't been sent yet. It only gets sent once all the message handlers have fully run.